# javascript regex and filetype in file upload

Tags: javascript, regex, file-upload

I have a file upload in my page. I defined an attribute with name: "filetype".

```
<input filetype=".jpg|.jpeg|.png" id="attachments" type="file">
```

I want when I select a file from file upload, with the javascript, I check file type:

```
    function onSelect(e) {
    if (!e.files[0].extension.match('/' + $("input[type='file']").attr('filetype') + '/i')) {
        alert('file type is wrong');
        e.preventDefault();
    }    
}
```

Now, when I select a file with .jpg format, e.files[0].extension would be

> .jpg

and 
'/' + $("input[type='file']").attr('filetype') + '/i' is

> /.jpg|.jpeg|.png/i

but e.files[0].extension.match('/' + $("input[type='file']").attr('filetype') + '/i') returns

> null

and then alert fires.
Why? and how I solve this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: You can't build a literal regex with concatenation, use the RegExp constructor.

Comment: Thanks alot. That's right. I use RegExp and it solved. Please write your comment as answer, that I marked is as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't build a literal regex with concatenation, you need to use the RegExp constructor.

I would suggest you do the following:

```
<input data-filetype="jpg|jpeg|png" id="attachments" type="file">
```

Then:

```
function onSelect(e) {
    // "this" is the file input
    // if you attach the function to an event
    // like `$('input:file').change(onSelect)`
    var filetypes = $(this).data('filetype');
    var re = RegExp('\\.('+ filetypes +')$','i');
    if (!re.test(e.files[0].extension)) {
        alert('file type is wrong');
        e.preventDefault();
    }    
}
```